# How to Install Kubuntu 22.04 Using a Pre-Existing /home Partition From 20.04?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu

Yesterday I decided to upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04. I had two partitions, one for the system, one for my home. The system partition didn't have enough space, while the home partition had a lot of free room. I decided to re-size the partitions using KDE Partition Manager.

Of course, it borked the system when trying to expand the / partition. So I was left with a dead / partition, and a non-accessible /home partition.

I used `testdisk` to salvage the configuration files from the dead / partition (bad super-block, unusable backups of it, failed magic number). Now, this is a touchscreen laptop with Windows 11 installed and a NVME drive. Everything was working fine before yesterday.

I installed 22.04 in the reformated/resized partition, but it also put my /home in there. I wanted to get my old /home partition integrated in the new install, but never found any option to make it work.

So now I have a / structure with a new /home in it (nvme0n1p9), plus my old /home in another partition (nvme0n1p10). While I should have some space in the / partition (I had 9GB free), after using `testdisk` to backup my old /home files, I get a "disk full" error and now I cannot even boot into it, I get a black screen and a cursor that won't move.

The partitions are:

- nvme0n1p1 150M Windows EFI, fat32 --works fine
- nvme0n1p2 128M Windows Reserved, unknown --no idea what it does, their spyware I guess
- nvme0n1p3 379.7G Main Windows 11, ntfs --works fine
- nvme0n1p7 244M Linux EFI, fat32 --created so I can start with Grub without touching the W11 EFI
- nvme0n1p9 31.36G Linux 22.04 Root + New Home, ext4 --inaccessible now, "disk full"
- unallocated 1M --after the resizing and moving, nothing I can do about it
- nvme0n1p10 39.08G Linux 20.04 /home, ext4 --I need this to be my /home!
- nvme0n1p8 7.45G Linux swap
- nvme0n1p4 990M Windows Recovery Tools, ntfs
- nvme0n1p5 16.5G Windows 11 image, ntfs
- unallocated 1M --I guess they also had issues partitioning exactly
- nvme0n1p6 1.36G Dell Support stuff, ntfs

I'm going to re-install 22.04 to nvme0n1p9, the 31.36G should be more than enough. I need someone to please tell me how to make sure the nvme0n1p10 is assigned as my /home partition without deleting anything there, during the installation process.

I've been trying to find a solution for hours but all I find is how to re-assign an old partition to a new install (I don't want to do this, I want things to fall organically in place during install), or how to create a separate /home partition while formatting it (I have a lot of important things there, and I don't have the room to back up all of them).

Comment: Can't you just re-install using the "*Something else*" type of option (Kubuntu uses the `ubiquity` installer which has a skin, sorry I can't recall what that option is called with the Qt skin Kubuntu uses) and just select the wanted partition has your HOME; I do it quite often in QA without issue; and often use the re-install option as it's faster than *release-upgrade* (inc. adding back the *manually installed* packages I'd installed). If you're not going to install (*I got confused as you spoke about both install & no-install*), just correct from *live* media by edits to *fstab* & boot.

Comment: I didn't have enough room in the root partition to upgrade directly, that's why I tried re-sizing first and that's when it all went awry.

Comment: All the online guides I've found seem to imply if you add a second partition to be your /home (separated from the system partition), it will be formatted.

Comment: Once you've setup your home partition on whatever drive you prefer, modify *fstab*.  You can use your current as an example, eg. my system here has `UUID=06863296-81b3-4263-8665-21f1864fa399 /home           xfs     defaults        0       0` where if I wanted to use another; I'd need to just change the UUID to match the newer location..  I'd copy the data as stated using *live* media; change the *file-system table* (`/etc/fstab`) to match what you need; once it's working perfectly you can remove the other directories (what will be *shadowed*)..  I'd also use UUIDs rather than *nnvme0n1p10*

Comment: If you need a walk-thru example; you'll have to wait for an answer written by someone else..

Answer (score 1):

It was easy to do. I apologize for the question.

Just add the same EFI partition (it cannot be formatted) for the launcher, add the old swap partition (it will be formatted, no matter what), use the main partition for the system (you choose to format it, of course) and add the old /home partition taking care 'format' is unchecked.

It's looking good.